# Episerver find all image references

Tags: c#, .net, episerver, optimizely

I'm trying to find all references to all images in all blocks.

1. I can get all images
2. I can't find all references in nested blocks.

```
var searchClient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IClient>();
var result = searchClient.Search<IContent>()
                         .For(item.Name)
                         .GetContentResult();
```

The code above returns me pages where the image is in the properties, but I cannot find a way to find images in the nested blocks.

Is there another way? or any other ideas?

Performance is for now is not a problem.

Comment: You may need to change how content is indexed to support your use case. By nested blocks, do you mean local block properties or blocks in content areas?

Comment: blocks in content areas

Comment: Did you set `ShouldIndexInContentAreaConvention` to ensure blocks in content areas are indexed with your content? https://world.optimizely.com/blogs/pjangid/dates/2019/4/indexing-blocks-content-to-make-it-searchable/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var referencedLinks = ContentRepository.GetReferencesToContent(item.ContentLink, false).Select(x => x.OwnerID);
var items = ContentRepository.GetItems(referencedLinks, LanguageSelector.AutoDetect());
```